# Native method not found while using .so File in libs Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have .so file which i have created using a c library .Now i want to use .so file in another project for call those functions. I don't know how to use that library. How to call any function from that library? I have tried but found error as Native method not found.I am a beginner with Ndk in android.any help on this..??

I have referred many links those were not solved my problem as 
[Native method not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100542/native-method-not-found),

[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312362/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method-not-found),

I am facing the same as this link but it is unanswered. link is 
[Need NDK Help: How to call a C++ function for shared library from another project that uses C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084560/need-ndk-help-how-to-call-a-c-function-for-shared-library-from-another-projec)

My Android.mk file is as follows from which i have created .so file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ShairportSample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ShairportSample.cpp
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Did you add that library to your main module as LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES in your Android.mk? Posting your Android.mk could really help here because there is no information about how you handle things.

Comment: @user2359247 mk file of project from which i have created .so file ??..as in another i don't have that file till now.

Comment: As I guessed, you don't add that shared library to your module. The answer should fix your problem.

Comment: @user2359247 Do i also need .mk file in Android Project.Calling project is not any Ndk project in my case. Is their a need to make it Native project also.?

Comment: @Manmohan, I guess You have Project A (JNI Project) and A.SO which you have generated by building A. And, above .mk file is of A project. Now, you want have Project B and you want to use A.SO in Project B. Is it the scenario? What is the nature of Project B than?

Comment: @KanakSony Yes this is exact scenario. Project B is is Simple Android Project instead of Native.

Answer (score 0):

you can call functions implemented inside the .so you want to reuse from another NDK lib, by setting it as prebuilt shared library your're depending on inside your **Android.mk** file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ShairportSample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_CPU_ABI)/libShairportSample.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := PATH_TO_ShairportSample.h
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := yournewlib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := yournewlib.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += ShairportSample
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

From your Java code you'll have to load ShairportSample lib from your Java before loading yournewlib.

Otherwise, if you want to reuse your .so directly from Java, you should export a Java library (.jar) that uses it. Then you can reuse this Java lib from your other project.

Comment: I have Project A (JNI Project) and A.SO which i have generated by building A. And, above .mk file is of A project. Now, i have Project B and want to use A.SO in Project B.Where i should add ur .mk file code in my project.

Comment: please tell me something for my previous comment as i am a newbie with Native Developments.

Comment: You should put this code into the Android.mk file of your project B.

Comment: For this i also need to provide native support to B project.? now Application.mk is also needed? what is the format for values like PATH_TO_ShairportSample.h

Comment: Yes, but if you want to use it from Java instead it's also possible. In this case you should make a Java library from your Project A as I said at the end of my answer. PATH_TO_ShairportSample can be for example projectA/jni/include

Comment: Ok, Now I have exported jar from .so file named shair.jar. Now how i can call methods from this jar of any of .c class. I know how to use normal jar. But with this jar i am not able to see any class from jar from which method can be called. please suggest me.

Comment: From your ProjectB you should be able to call all the public methods declared by your ProjectA. It's like with a normal jar, it's ProjectA that calls all the C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

1. first of all, you should make sure the .so file being compiled correctly, named it like this libYourLibName.so, put it into libs/armeabi folder.
2. secondly, make sure you have loaded the .so file from static block

> static {
>       System.loadLibrary("YourLibName");
>   }

may this will help you